# Coffeescript Cakefile - Array of cmdline options

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

Is it possible to pass multiple cmdline args to a Cakefile and capture those values in an array? For example something like this:

```
option '', '--compilation-level [LEVEL]', 'Description...'
task "build", "compile js", (options)->
    compilationLevels = options['compilation-level'] || ['DEFAULT']
    if compilationLevels.length >= 2
        console.log 'multiple compiles'
    else
        console.log 'just one compile'
```

Then run it w/ `cake --compilation-level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS --compilation-level SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS build`

If this is not possible then suggestions on the most optimal way to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep: Cake is powered by CoffeeScript's [OptionParser](http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/optparse.html), which is ported from the Ruby utility of the same name. If you search the source for `isList`, you'll see that an option can be used multiple times to create an array if (and only if) the regex

```
OPTIONAL   = /\[(\w+(\*?))\]/
```

is fully matched by the long flag name. In short: **You just have to add one character to your code.**

```
option '', '--compilation-level [LEVEL*]', 'Description...'
```

That `*` makes all the difference! :)